# r1soft SOAP - Decrypting Disk Safe

Tags: php, soap, r1soft

I'm working on a utility that will allow users to quickly check the backup quality of multiple servers worth of backups (we get a not-insignificant number of false negatives from the automatic reporting).

I am able to pull RecoveryPoint info just fine, but when it actually comes to checking their contents, SOAP throws an exception, citing: "SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Encrypted disk safe has not yet been decrypted"

I do have an encryption key, so r1soft isn't making this up. But how do I get the encryption key to r1soft through SOAP so that I can access this RecoveryPoint? The only functions that will accept an encryption key that I can see from the documentation have to do with MySQL databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while, but I was finally able to get a hold of someone at r1Soft support who knew what I was talking about, and they were able to tell me that there are **no methods for dealing with an encrypted disk safe using soap**. I'm going to escalate the cause a bit more, but as of right now, what I am asking seems to be impossible.